# Form Cross domain POST request using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to send data from a form to a php file so I can store it in a database, but its not working...

The code for the form is not on the same server as the php file, because the form will be on a mobile app.

html

```
<div data-role="page" id="createclub">

<div data-role="content">
    <form id="cname" align="left" action="post">
        <label for="name">Enter Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" value=""  />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-inline="true">
    </form>

    <div id="result"></div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cname").submit( function () {
        $.post(
        'http://www.clubbedin.isadcharity.org/createclub.php',
        $("#cname").serialize(),
        function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
        alert("Data " + data);
        }
        );
        return false;
        });
        });
    </script>
```

php file

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add this at the beginning of your PHP file:

```
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
```

More info on cross domain policy [here](http://www.cypressnorth.com/blog/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/).

Comment: Please accept my answer in that case.. Why did you accept someone else's answer if it isn't correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to prevent the default function of the submit button using `.preventDefault()` because as I look on your code you want to submit your form using ajax

```
 $("#cname").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.clubbedin.isadcharity.org/createclub.php',
        crossDomain: true, //set as a cross domain requests
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#cname").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
            alert("Data " + data);
        },
    });
});
```

and please use `.ajax()` so that you can set your ajax request to a cross-domain request

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: as Mahan siad, if you use .ajax you can do cross domain

Answer (score -1):

Your input element `<input type="text" id="name" value=""  />` must set up the name attribute as `name="name"`.

form `#cname` after edited

```
<form id="cname" align="left" action="post">
    <label for="name">Enter Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""  />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-inline="true">
</form>
```

You can gather more informations from the jQuery API Documention:
http://api.jquery.com/
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/