# Use existing contactform plugin in Wordpress for posting to another domain instead of custom form with own validation?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form

I have created a new **website B** (in Wordpress) based on **website A** (made in asp). The website A has some special functionality made in ASP ´(which I don't have any control over).

One of these asp-pages has a "normal" contactform that sends mail and inserts some data into a specific database.

I thought that using a contactform plugin would make this easy. I've tried with CF7 (Contact Form 7) so I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel once more with validation of form field ,usage of recaptcha etc.

I would basically want to "do the validation etc" based on the CF7 plugin and after that I want to post the whole form (not ajax) to a page on **website A**.

Something like

- User clicks submit on **website B** on contactpage
- Validation (javascript) is done on **website B**
- User is sent to **website A** with values posted from **website B**
- ASP-script validates form field values (server validation) and redirects to the contactpage on **website B** if one or more fields not ok (this is just for extra security, most of cases js-validation would be enough)
- If everything is ok and data is inserted in database as expected then **website A** redirects to **website B** to a "thank you page"

My attempt to achieve this:

Under additional settings for the actual contactform in Wordpress i set this:
**demo_mode: on** so no mail is created/sent in the Wordpress installation (because this is done later on on **website A**) and then this is my currestion jQuery...

```
jQuery(function ($) {

     //Submit whole form to a specific url
     //#wpcf7-f16670-p16067-o1 form is the form created by CF7 plugin
     //
     var url_action = 'url to website A';       
     $("#wpcf7-f16670-p16067-o1 form").attr("action", url_action);

    $( "#wpcf7-f16670-p16067-o1 form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $( "#wpcf7-f16670-p16067-o1 form" ).submit();

    });

});
```

`$( "#wpcf7-f16670-p16067-o1 form" ).submit();` makes a recursive loop because $`( "#wpcf7-f16670-p16067-o1 form" ).submit(function( event )` is executed each time `submit()` is executed.

My original thought that a plugin would be make life easier, but now I'm not so sure anymore... **Maybe I am overdoing this?**

I have also tried posting form with ajax but then there are issue with crossdomain posting. I know it's possible to solve this as well, but I also know that just copying the form from **website A** to **website B** works but then I would have to do the validation and the recaptha myself.

Comment: If you're not using ajax, how can website A redirect to website B if you have no control over website A?

Comment: ok forgive me for the confusion. Its up to my customer to do that redirection, but I don't have access to change the code myself

Comment: Okay. I would make a fake website A where you can debug problems with, and once ready, instruct the customer to return the redirect response you desire.  Your customer will be required to allow cross origin access. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952383/form-cross-domain-post-request-using-php  However, you'll need to find something similar for ASP.

Comment: Thanks for ur input/feedback. Its not the actual response that is my issue but how I would go about to achieve the posting. Shoud I use CF7 plugin or should just create a custom form and post the data "as normal" set to action "contactpage website A" ? What would you do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin, but it is popular and I would most likely use the plugin if it allows me to customize validation.  If something goes wrong, it's not incredibly difficult to make your own form with validation.  The form itself seems like the least of your concerns.

Comment: Ok thanks again for your feedback :-)